# How do you add to context menu "Open as Read Only" in Windows 7/Vista for docx, doc, xls, etc

Tags: windows-7, context-menu

Microsoft word has a built-in way to open files as Read only from context menu. If you Shift+RightClick you get an option but it doesn't work.

If you look online for this you will find a lot of ways for Windows XP to fix the Shift right click ([Link](http://word.tips.net/T000597_Opening_a_Document_as_Read-Only_in_Windows_Explorer.html)) context menu option. But for windows 7, I couldn't find anything.

Comment: Found three ways to fix this:

1. Edit the registry manually. (Be sure to backup the registry first)
2. I found this cool app named "Creative Elements Power Tools" that has a tool called "File Type Doctor" that lets you follow the instructions provided in the link just like you could in Windows XP.
3. Copy and paste following code into a document with .reg extension and execute it(BACKUP YOUR REGISTRY FIRST)

Comment: I will answer my own question asap, but i have to wait 7 hours first -.-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found three ways to fix this:

1. Edit the registry manually. (Be sure to backup the registry first)
2. I found this cool app named "Creative Elements Power Tools" that has a tool called "File Type Doctor" that lets you follow the instructions provided in the link just like you could in Windows XP.
3. Copy and paste following code into a document with .reg extension and execute it(BACKUP YOUR REGISTRY FIRST)

   Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.docx]
   @="Word.Document.12"
   "PerceivedType"="document"
   "Content Type"="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"

   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Document.12]
   @="Documento de Microsoft Office Word"
   "BrowserFlags"=dword:2C
   "EditFlags"=hex:00,00,00,00

   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID{F4754C9B-64F5-4B40-8AF4-679732AC0607}]
   @="Documento de Microsoft Office Word"
   "IPersistStorageType"=dword:0000002
   "MainPartContentType"="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document.main+xml"

   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.docx\OpenWithList]

   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.docx\PersistentHandler]
   @="{D3B41FA1-01E3-49AF-AA25-1D0D824275AE}"

   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.docx\ShellEx]

   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.docx\Word.Document.12]

   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.docx\OpenWithList\WordPad.exe]
   @=""

   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.docx\ShellEx\PropertyHandler]
   @="{993BE281-6695-4BA5-8A2A-7AACBFAAB69E}"

   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.docx\ShellEx{8895b1c6-b41f-4c1c-a562-0d564250836f}]
   @="{84F66100-FF7C-4fb4-B0C0-02CD7FB668FE}"

   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.docx\ShellEx{BB2E617C-0920-11d1-9A0B-00C04FC2D6C1}]
   @="{C41662BB-1FA0-4CE0-8DC5-9B7F8279FF97}"

   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.docx\Word.Document.12\ShellNew]
   "NullFile"=""

   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Document.12\CLSID]
   @="{F4754C9B-64F5-4B40-8AF4-679732AC0607}"

   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Document.12\DefaultIcon]
   @="C:\Windows\Installer\{90120000-0030-0000-0000-0000000FF1CE}\wordicon.exe,13"

   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Document.12\DocObject]
   @="16"

   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Document.12\HTML Handler]
   @="\"C:\PROGRA~1\MICROS~1\Office12\MSOHTMED.EXE\" \"%1\""

   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Document.12\Insertable]

   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Document.12\protocol]

   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Document.12\shell]
   @="Open"

   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Document.12\XML Handler]

   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Document.12\HTML Handler\Icon]
   @=".dochtml"
   ".htm"=".dochtml"
   ".html"=".dochtml"
   ".mhtml"=".docmhtml"
   ".mht"=".docmhtml"

   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Document.12\HTML Handler\shell]

   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Document.12\HTML Handler\shell\edit]

   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Document.12\HTML Handler\shell\PrintWithOptions]

   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Document.12\HTML Handler\shell\edit\command]
   @="\"C:\PROGRA~1\MICROS~1\Office12\MSOHTMED.EXE\" /o0 \"%1\""

   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Document.12\HTML Handler\shell\PrintWithOptions\command]
   @="\"C:\PROGRA~1\MICROS~1\Office12\WINWORD.EXE\" /n"

   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Document.12\HTML Handler\shell\PrintWithOptions\ddeexec]
   @="[Dim dlg as FilePrint][FileOpen(\"%1\")][t=IsDocumentDirty()][GetCurValues dlg][n = Dialog dlg][if n = -1 then FilePrint dlg][SetDocumentDirty t][DocClose]"

   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Document.12\HTML Handler\shell\PrintWithOptions\ddeexec\Application]
   @="WinWord"

   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Document.12\HTML Handler\shell\PrintWithOptions\ddeexec\ifexec]
   @="[Dim dlg as FilePrint][FileOpen(\"%1\")][GetCurValues dlg][n = Dialog dlg][if n = -1 then FilePrint dlg][FileExit 2]"

   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Document.12\HTML Handler\shell\PrintWithOptions\ddeexec\Topic]
   @="System"

   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Document.12\protocol\StdFileEditing]

   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Document.12\protocol\StdFileEditing\RequestDataFormats]
   @="NoteshNote,NotesDocAction"

   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Document.12\protocol\StdFileEditing\server]
   @="C:\PROGRA~1\MICROS~1\Office12\WINWORD.EXE"

   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Document.12\protocol\StdFileEditing\SetDataFormats]
   @="NotesDocInfo"

   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Document.12\protocol\StdFileEditing\Verb]

   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Document.12\protocol\StdFileEditing\Verb\0]
   @="Edit"

   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Document.12\shell\Edit]
   @="&Editar"

   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Document.12\shell\New]
   @="&Nuevo"

   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Document.12\shell\OnenotePrintto]
   @="&Imprimir"
   "Extended"=""

   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Document.12\shell\Open]
   @="&Abrir"

   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Document.12\shell\OpenAsReadOnly]
   @="Abrir en modo de sólo lectura"
   "Extended"=""

   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Document.12\shell\Print]
   @="&Imprimir"

   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Document.12\shell\Printto]

   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Document.12\shell\Edit\command]
   @="\"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office12\WINWORD.EXE\" /n /dde"
   "command"=hex(7):76,00,55,00,70,00,41,00,56,00,58,00,21,00,21,00,21,00,21,00,21,00,21,00,21,00,21,00,21,00,4D,00,4B,00,4B,00,53,00,6B,00,57,00,4F,00,52,00,44,00,46,00,69,00,6C,00,65,00,73,00,3E,00,74,00,57,00,7B,00,7E,00,24,00,34,00,51,00,5D,00,63,00,40,00,35,00,64,00,31,00,60,00,2C,00,78,00,61,00,54,00,4F,00,35,00,20,00,2F,00,6E,00,20,00,2F,00,64,00,64,00,65,00,00,00,00,00

   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Document.12\shell\Edit\ddeexec]
   @="[REM _DDE_Direct][FileOpen(\"%1\")]"

   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Document.12\shell\Edit\ddeexec\Application]
   @="WinWord"

   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Document.12\shell\Edit\ddeexec\Topic]
   @="System"

   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Document.12\shell\New\command]
   @="\"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office12\WINWORD.EXE\" /n /f /dde"
   "command"=hex(7):76,00,55,00,70,00,41,00,56,00,58,00,21,00,21,00,21,00,21,00,21,00,21,00,21,00,21,00,21,00,4D,00,4B,00,4B,00,53,00,6B,00,57,00,4F,00,52,00,44,00,46,00,69,00,6C,00,65,00,73,00,3E,00,74,00,57,00,7B,00,7E,00,24,00,34,00,51,00,5D,00,63,00,40,00,35,00,64,00,31,00,60,00,2C,00,78,00,61,00,54,00,4F,00,35,00,20,00,2F,00,6E,00,20,00,2F,00,66,00,20,00,2F,00,64,00,64,00,65,00,00,00,00,00

   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Document.12\shell\New\ddeexec]
   @="[REM _DDE_Direct][FileNew(\"%1\")]"

   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Document.12\shell\New\ddeexec\Application]
   @="WinWord"

   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Document.12\shell\New\ddeexec\Topic]
   @="System"

   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Document.12\shell\OnenotePrintto\command]
   @="\"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office12\WINWORD.EXE\" /n /dde"
   "command"=hex(7):76,00,55,00,70,00,41,00,56,00,58,00,21,00,21,00,21,00,21,00,21,00,21,00,21,00,21,00,21,00,4D,00,4B,00,4B,00,53,00,6B,00,57,00,4F,00,52,00,44,00,46,00,69,00,6C,00,65,00,73,00,3E,00,74,00,57,00,7B,00,7E,00,24,00,34,00,51,00,5D,00,63,00,40,00,35,00,64,00,31,00,60,00,2C,00,78,00,61,00,54,00,4F,00,35,00,20,00,2F,00,6E,00,20,00,2F,00,64,00,64,00,65,00,00,00,00,00

   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Document.12\shell\OnenotePrintto\ddeexec]
   @="[REM _DDE_Minimize][FileOpen(\"%1\")][FilePrintSetup \"%2 on p\",.DoNotSetAsSysDefault=1][FilePrint 0][DocClose][FilePrintSetup \"\"]"

   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Document.12\shell\OnenotePrintto\ddeexec\Application]
   @="WinWord"

   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Document.12\shell\OnenotePrintto\ddeexec\ifexec]
   @="[FileOpen(\"%1\")][FilePrintSetup \"%2 on p\",.DoNotSetAsSysDefault=1][FilePrint 0][FileExit 2]"

   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Document.12\shell\OnenotePrintto\ddeexec\Topic]
   @="System"

   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Document.12\shell\Open\command]
   @="\"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office12\WINWORD.EXE\" /n /dde"
   "command"=hex(7):76,00,55,00,70,00,41,00,56,00,58,00,21,00,21,00,21,00,21,00,21,00,21,00,21,00,21,00,21,00,4D,00,4B,00,4B,00,53,00,6B,00,57,00,4F,00,52,00,44,00,46,00,69,00,6C,00,65,00,73,00,3E,00,74,00,57,00,7B,00,7E,00,24,00,34,00,51,00,5D,00,63,00,40,00,35,00,64,00,31,00,60,00,2C,00,78,00,61,00,54,00,4F,00,35,00,20,00,2F,00,6E,00,20,00,2F,00,64,00,64,00,65,00,00,00,00,00

   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Document.12\shell\Open\ddeexec]
   @="[REM _DDE_Direct][FileOpen(\"%1\")]"

   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Document.12\shell\Open\ddeexec\Application]
   @="WinWord"

   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Document.12\shell\Open\ddeexec\Topic]
   @="System"

   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Document.12\shell\OpenAsReadOnly\command]
   @="\"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office12\WINWORD.EXE\" /h /n /dde"
   "command"=hex(7):76,00,55,00,70,00,41,00,56,00,58,00,21,00,21,00,21,00,21,00,21,00,21,00,21,00,21,00,21,00,4D,00,4B,00,4B,00,53,00,6B,00,57,00,4F,00,52,00,44,00,46,00,69,00,6C,00,65,00,73,00,3E,00,74,00,57,00,7B,00,7E,00,24,00,34,00,51,00,5D,00,63,00,40,00,35,00,64,00,31,00,60,00,2C,00,78,00,61,00,54,00,4F,00,35,00,20,00,2F,00,68,00,20,00,2F,00,6E,00,20,00,2F,00,64,00,64,00,65,00,00,00,00,00

   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Document.12\shell\OpenAsReadOnly\ddeexec]
   @="[AppShow][REM _DDE_ReadWriteOnSave][FileOpen .Name=\"%1\",.ReadOnly=1]"

   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Document.12\shell\OpenAsReadOnly\ddeexec\Application]
   @="WinWord"

   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Document.12\shell\OpenAsReadOnly\ddeexec\IfExec]
   @=""

   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Document.12\shell\OpenAsReadOnly\ddeexec\Topic]
   @="System"

   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Document.12\shell\Print\command]
   @="\"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office12\WINWORD.EXE\" /x /n /dde"
   "command"=hex(7):76,00,55,00,70,00,41,00,56,00,58,00,21,00,21,00,21,00,21,00,21,00,21,00,21,00,21,00,21,00,4D,00,4B,00,4B,00,53,00,6B,00,57,00,4F,00,52,00,44,00,46,00,69,00,6C,00,65,00,73,00,3E,00,74,00,57,00,7B,00,7E,00,24,00,34,00,51,00,5D,00,63,00,40,00,35,00,64,00,31,00,60,00,2C,00,78,00,61,00,54,00,4F,00,35,00,20,00,2F,00,78,00,20,00,2F,00,6E,00,20,00,2F,00,64,00,64,00,65,00,00,00,00,00

   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Document.12\shell\Print\ddeexec]
   @="[REM _DDE_Minimize][FileOpen(\"%1\")][t=IsDocumentDirty()][FilePrint 0][SetDocumentDirty t][DocClose]"

   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Document.12\shell\Print\ddeexec\Application]
   @="WinWord"

   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Document.12\shell\Print\ddeexec\ifexec]
   @="[FileOpen(\"%1\")][FilePrint 0][FileExit 2]"

   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Document.12\shell\Print\ddeexec\Topic]
   @="System"

   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Document.12\shell\Printto\command]
   @="\"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office12\WINWORD.EXE\" /n /dde"
   "command"=hex(7):76,00,55,00,70,00,41,00,56,00,58,00,21,00,21,00,21,00,21,00,21,00,21,00,21,00,21,00,21,00,4D,00,4B,00,4B,00,53,00,6B,00,57,00,4F,00,52,00,44,00,46,00,69,00,6C,00,65,00,73,00,3E,00,74,00,57,00,7B,00,7E,00,24,00,34,00,51,00,5D,00,63,00,40,00,35,00,64,00,31,00,60,00,2C,00,78,00,61,00,54,00,4F,00,35,00,20,00,2F,00,6E,00,20,00,2F,00,64,00,64,00,65,00,00,00,00,00

   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Document.12\shell\Printto\ddeexec]
   @="[REM _DDE_Minimize][FileOpen(\"%1\")][FilePrintSetup \"%2 on p\",.DoNotSetAsSysDefault=1][FilePrint 0][DocClose 2][FilePrintSetup \"\"]"

   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Document.12\shell\Printto\ddeexec\Application]
   @="WinWord"

   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Document.12\shell\Printto\ddeexec\ifexec]
   @="[FileOpen(\"%1\")][FilePrintSetup \"%2 on p\",.DoNotSetAsSysDefault=1][FilePrint 0][FileExit 2]"

   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Document.12\shell\Printto\ddeexec\Topic]
   @="System"

   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Document.12\XML Handler\Icon]
   @=".docxml"
   ".xml"=".docxml"

   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID{F4754C9B-64F5-4B40-8AF4-679732AC0607}\AuxUserType]

   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID{F4754C9B-64F5-4B40-8AF4-679732AC0607}\Conversion]

   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID{F4754C9B-64F5-4B40-8AF4-679732AC0607}\DataFormats]

   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID{F4754C9B-64F5-4B40-8AF4-679732AC0607}\DefaultExtension]
   @=".docx,Word Document (.docx)"

   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID{F4754C9B-64F5-4B40-8AF4-679732AC0607}\DefaultIcon]
   @="C:\PROGRA~1\MICROS~1\Office12\WINWORD.EXE,1"

   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID{F4754C9B-64F5-4B40-8AF4-679732AC0607}\DocObject]
   @="16"

   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID{F4754C9B-64F5-4B40-8AF4-679732AC0607}\InprocHandler32]
   @="ole32.dll"

   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID{F4754C9B-64F5-4B40-8AF4-679732AC0607}\Insertable]

   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID{F4754C9B-64F5-4B40-8AF4-679732AC0607}\LocalServer32]
   @="C:\PROGRA~1\MICROS~1\Office12\WINWORD.EXE"
   "LocalServer32"=hex(7):76,00,55,00,70,00,41,00,56,00,58,00,21,00,21,00,21,00,21,00,21,00,21,00,21,00,21,00,21,00,4D,00,4B,00,4B,00,53,00,6B,00,57,00,4F,00,52,00,44,00,46,00,69,00,6C,00,65,00,73,00,3E,00,74,00,57,00,7B,00,7E,00,24,00,34,00,51,00,5D,00,63,00,40,00,35,00,64,00,31,00,60,00,2C,00,78,00,61,00,54,00,4F,00,35,00,00,00,00,00

   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID{F4754C9B-64F5-4B40-8AF4-679732AC0607}\MiscStatus]
   @="0"

   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID{F4754C9B-64F5-4B40-8AF4-679732AC0607}\OfficeCompliant]
   @="0"

   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID{F4754C9B-64F5-4B40-8AF4-679732AC0607}\Printable]

   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID{F4754C9B-64F5-4B40-8AF4-679732AC0607}\ProgID]
   @="Word.Document.12"

   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID{F4754C9B-64F5-4B40-8AF4-679732AC0607}\TypeLib]
   @="{00020905-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}"

   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID{F4754C9B-64F5-4B40-8AF4-679732AC0607}\Verb]

   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID{F4754C9B-64F5-4B40-8AF4-679732AC0607}\Version]
   @="12"

   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID{F4754C9B-64F5-4B40-8AF4-679732AC0607}\VersionIndependentProgID]
   @="Word.Document"

   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID{F4754C9B-64F5-4B40-8AF4-679732AC0607}\AuxUserType\2]
   @="Documento"

   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID{F4754C9B-64F5-4B40-8AF4-679732AC0607}\AuxUserType\3]
   @="Microsoft Office Word"

   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID{F4754C9B-64F5-4B40-8AF4-679732AC0607}\Conversion\Readable]

   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID{F4754C9B-64F5-4B40-8AF4-679732AC0607}\Conversion\Readwritable]

   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID{F4754C9B-64F5-4B40-8AF4-679732AC0607}\Conversion\Readable\Main]
   @="MSWordDocx,MSWordDocm,MSWordDotx,MSWordDotm,MSWordDoc,1"

   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID{F4754C9B-64F5-4B40-8AF4-679732AC0607}\Conversion\Readwritable\Main]
   @="MSWordDocx,MSWordDocm,MSWordDotx,MSWordDotm,MSWordDoc,MSWordPic"

   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID{F4754C9B-64F5-4B40-8AF4-679732AC0607}\DataFormats\DefaultFile]
   @="MSWordDocx"

   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID{F4754C9B-64F5-4B40-8AF4-679732AC0607}\DataFormats\DelayRenderFormats]

   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID{F4754C9B-64F5-4B40-8AF4-679732AC0607}\DataFormats\GetSet]

   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID{F4754C9B-64F5-4B40-8AF4-679732AC0607}\DataFormats\PriorityCacheFormats]

   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID{F4754C9B-64F5-4B40-8AF4-679732AC0607}\DataFormats\DelayRenderFormats\0]
   @="Woozle"

   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID{F4754C9B-64F5-4B40-8AF4-679732AC0607}\DataFormats\GetSet\0]
   @="Embed_Source,1,8,1"

   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID{F4754C9B-64F5-4B40-8AF4-679732AC0607}\DataFormats\GetSet\1]
   @="1,1,1,3"

   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID{F4754C9B-64F5-4B40-8AF4-679732AC0607}\DataFormats\GetSet\2]
   @="3,1,32,1"

   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID{F4754C9B-64F5-4B40-8AF4-679732AC0607}\DataFormats\GetSet\3]
   @="HTML Format,1,1,3"

   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID{F4754C9B-64F5-4B40-8AF4-679732AC0607}\DataFormats\GetSet\4]
   @="Rich Text Format,1,1,3"

   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID{F4754C9B-64F5-4B40-8AF4-679732AC0607}\DataFormats\GetSet\5]
   @="NoteshNote, -1,1,1"

   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID{F4754C9B-64F5-4B40-8AF4-679732AC0607}\DataFormats\PriorityCacheFormats\0]
   @="Rich Text Format"

   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID{F4754C9B-64F5-4B40-8AF4-679732AC0607}\Verb\0]
   @="&Editar,0,2"

   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID{F4754C9B-64F5-4B40-8AF4-679732AC0607}\Verb\1]
   @="&Abrir,0,2"